# How to remove listview margin?

Tags: android

I am adding a scrollable listview to a relative layout but it's adding a margin to the right and the bottom of it. Does anyone have an idea how to remove that?

```
<RelativeLayout layout_width="match_parent" layout_height="match_parent">
       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/listheader" layout_width="match_parent" layout_height="wrap_content">           
       </LinearLayout>
       <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/listheader" android:listSelector="@drawable/item_background"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: solved it by removing `android:scrollbars="vertical"`

Comment: @Satya You do realize you can answer your own questions? If you add your solution as an answer then after some time you can accept it. That might be nice (and more clear) for future visitors.

Comment: @Bart Here's a blog post related to your comment [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by removing android:scrollbars="vertical"